# Visual Studio reports timeout when connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

Odd issue, I've installed MySQL for Visual Studio and the .Net connector (both the latest, have also checked for updates).

Running Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Update 3.

The MySQL server is running on my VPS (which is running CentOS).
Running `nmap -sT -O "myip" -p 3306`  (definitely using `myip` and not `localhost` as I've heard that can report wrong, depending on the setup) from the server reports:

`PORT  STATE SERVICE

3306/tcp open  mysql`

Additionally, I can connect from my dev machine using MySQL workbench, everything works fine.

I've tried using the advanced properties in Visual Studio (from the Add Connection menu) to change the default connect timeout and default command timeout to higher values, no success. It still just reports timeout. I've also tried setting Allow Zero Datetime to True with no success.

At this point I'm stuck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK scrap that, issue seems to have resolved itself. Not entirely sure what changed...

Answer (score 1):

Late answer here: I was experiencing this issue with Visual Studio 2015 and MySQL remote database. I changed the Timeout parameter and that solved it.

Looks like the connection to a remote MySQL database takes longer than VS accepts by default.

Comment: I did try that with VS12, maybe it's improved somewhat since then. Thanks for the feedback.